# Integral over operators equal -When are operators equal?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

This is a physics motivated question from quantum mechanics. When I have two operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ acting on the Hilbertspace $\mathbb{C}-L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with
$$\int\psi^*(x)\hat{A}\psi(x)\:\mathrm{d}x= \int\psi^*(x)\hat{B}\psi(x)\:\mathrm{d}x $$
and where the initial conditions of $\psi$ can be arbitrary how can I then conclude $\hat{A}= \hat{B}$?

Comment: Your question would be much easier to understand if you explained some more details, such as what are the spaces where your operators act.  Also, how do the integrands depend on $x$?

Comment: @Ruy you are right I changed it.

Comment: The "initial conditions" doesn't make sense unless you are very specifically referring to solving some ODE in that Hilbert space (presumably, in QM, the Schrödinger equation).

This is already false in finite dimensions, $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ satisfy
$\langle x,Ax\rangle = \langle x, Bx\rangle$ for all $x\in(\mathbb{R}^2,g_{\text{Euclidean}})$.

Comment: However, if you had
$$
\int \phi^*(x) A\psi(x) dx = \int \phi^*(x)A\psi(x)dx
$$
for all $\phi,\psi$ you could use non-degeneracy of the inner product to deduce
$$0=\langle \phi, (A-B)\psi\rangle\qquad\forall \phi\implies (A-B)\psi=0$$
for every $\psi$, and you're done.

Comment: @topolosaurus I have found out that for a complex inner product it‘s also true if $\phi$=$\psi$, but my problem is that I think I get not all $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb{C})$ with arbitrary initial conditions of the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: Silas, I think you are confusing notations. If you're studying QM in 1 spatial dimension the relevant Hilbert space (at this level) is $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$, the space of complex valued functions on the real line that are square integrable (modulo functions that are almost everywhere equal).

I suggest you rephrase your question to add more details about what you mean concerning initial conditions. As stated, your question is a general question regarding some particular Hilbert space.

Comment: My first example showed that what you wanted to prove is false is an easier Hilbert space, but I fear that it has confused you more than clarify anything.